# Loop for powershell script

Tags: powershell, loops

I'm from Linux world and currently got stuck with powershell.
I run the pwsh script which check the warranty of DELL devices based on given Serial number of device:

```
.\Get-DellWarrantyInfo.ps1 GZ80E5X2
```

Output looks like this:

```
Service Tag   : GZ80E5X2
Model         : POWEREDGE R740XD
Type          : poweredge-r740xd
Ship Date     : 05-07-19
Warranty Exp. : 05-08-22
```

I have the text file with the Serial numbers of devices to be checked, so I'd like to check them all at once.
Is there a way how to achieve such automation in powershell?

Something like I know from Bash:

```
for serial in `cat list.txt`; do runscript $serial; done
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Either of these should work

```
foreach ($serial in (Get-Content list.txt)){
    .\Get-DellWarrantyInfo.ps1 $serial
}
```

or

```
Get-Content list.txt | ForEach-Object {.\Get-DellWarrantyInfo.ps1 $_ }
```

You may use `cat` as an alias for `Get-Content` if that is more comfortable.  You may see a list of command alias using `Get-Alias`

Comment: I've reconsidered and agree that it is more appropriate to use the cmdlet.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Also note that `cat` is only an alias for `Get-Content` _on Windows_. If you run the cross-platform PowerShell (Core) 7+ edition on a Unix-like platform, `cat` invokes the native utility.